# Hyperlink errors when creating page break/readmore tag with php

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I am having this code which when loaded for the first time should show data from my database until  tag which is included on the mysql record data. Then it should show all the data when I click on read more but it is throwing a syntax error on my code editor. What mistake am I making on line 36 and 42 or what should I do to make the link to work? (see screenshot attached for error [JPEG attachment](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kabyxgui0xq7dg/Screenshot.JPG?dl=0) )

```
<?PHP
// include connection page
include("config.php");
// select data from pages table in database
$str = "SELECT * FROM pages";
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $str.=" WHERE ID=$id";
}
$pages_query = $mysqli->query($str)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

// fetch all data in an array
$pages_fetch = $pages_query->fetch_assoc();

// assign page data to $data variable
$data = $pages_fetch['Data'];
$separator = "</break>";
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    $data = explode($separator,$data);
    echo $data[0];
    echo "<br /><a href='pages.php?id=".$pages_fetch['ID']."'>More...</a>";
}else{
echo str_replace($separator,"",$data);
}
?>
```

And then print data from table:

```
<?PHP
    // include connection page
    include("config.php");
    // select data from pages table in database
    $pages_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pages")or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    // fetch all data in an array
    $pages_fetch = $pages_query->fetch_assoc();
    // assign page data to $data variable
    $data = $pages_fetch['Data'];
    Split page contents with </break> separator
    $data = explode("</break>",$data);
    // print data before </break> tag
    echo $data[0];

    // print readmore… link in page
    echo <a href='pages.php?id=".$pages_fetch['ID']."'>More...</a>";

    ?>
```

Data dump for the table

```
CREATE TABLE `aba_db`.`pages` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`Title` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`Data` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
`Status` INT NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

You can use this data in the Data field

Fernando was taken unconscious to a hospital, where he died four days later. Pathologists said he had 30 bruises and brain hemorrhaging, signs of a fatal beating. Olivas did not testify at his trial but denied guilt and continues to maintain his innocence, defense lawyer Peter Gold said Friday. `</break>`
In a 3-0 ruling Thursday, the First District Court of Appeal rejected defense claims that the prosecutor had discriminatory motives in removing four Latinos from the jury panel.
The court cited the trial judge's findings that the prosecutor had offered acceptable race-neutral reasons. For example, the court said, one juror was 20 years old, another indicated a willingness to question medical testimony, and a third had a daughter who was a social worker, which might lead the juror to have liberal views on crime.

Comment: comment line `Split page contents with </break> separator` and correct syntax of line  `echo "<a href='pages.php?id=".$pages_fetch['ID']."'>More...</a>";`

Comment: @Saty  
It now throws an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\hyperlink_test\readmore.php on line 10 and this is the line 10 `$pages_query = $mysqli->query($str)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));`

Comment: Check are you able to get the value of `id` in `readmore.php` page

Comment: Please label the code with the filenames. Did you show us `readmore.php`??

Comment: And why is it running `readmore.php` when your link is to `pages.php`??

Comment: Also in the code under the heading _And then print data from table:_ you are getting every row from the `pages` table i.e. __There is no WHERE clause__ Surely that also need to know an ID so you get the right page